# Is it possible to make awaitReactions give everyone who reacted a role?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Error: (node:2552) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: message.member.roles.add is not a function

Code:

```
   msg.react('')
    let collected = await msg.awaitReactions(() => true, {
        time: time
    }).then(collected => {

       var reaction = collected.first();

        message.member.roles.add('743917402714275971')
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. I will guide you through the code below step by step.

```js
msg.react('')
await msg.awaitReactions(() => true, {
    time: time
}).then(collected => {

    collected.users.cache.forEach((user) => {
        msg.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('743917402714275971');
    })

})
```

So `collected` returns a collection of [users](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/master/class/MessageReaction?scrollTo=users).
You have to iterate through them and get the `user` object for each of them.
Afterwards, you have to get the `GuildMember` object of users by getting the user from the guild using the `user` ID. From there, you can interact with the returned `GuildMember` object of each user who reacted to the message and add the role.

Comment: (node:4628) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'cache' of undefined it goes as a error

Comment: What does ``console.log(collected)`` return?

Comment: returns as Collection [Map] {
  '�' => MessageReaction {
    message: Message {
      channel: [TextChannel],
      deleted: false,
      id: '746894974192320543',
      type: 'DEFAULT',
      content: '',
      author: [ClientUser],
      pinned: false,
      tts: false,
      nonce: undefined,
      system: false,
      embeds: [Array],
      attachments: Collection [Map] {},
      createdTimestamp: 1598144038485,
      editedTimestamp: null,
      reactions: [Collection [Map]],
      mentions: [MessageMentions],
      webhookID: null,
      hit: null,